# Android xml attributes equivalent to Java code

Tags: java, android, xml

is there any documentation page that shows which android `XML` attributes are equivalent to android Java code? for example I have a `TextView` something like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="v0.5 (beta)"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

I need an online documentation page or something that shows/list all of the used java code which equivalent to the above attributes. I.e:

`android:id` is equivalent to `setId(int id)`

`android:text` is equivalent to `setText(String string)`

... and so on

I hope you guys got the idea of what I want.

Comment: The official android documentation has most of this.

Comment: @Tushar show me an example please. I've tried to look for something similar but I had no luck.

Comment: Depends on the UI element. Example: [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: @RobinVanPersi see the `Related Methods` section of every attribute. Example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Under 'XML Attributes' section.